# Overriding Ember's default behavior in {{linkTo}}

Tags: ember.js

The ember guide on {{linkTo}} says:

> By default, Ember.js will replace the segment with the value of the object's id property.

I would like to use a different property say profileName(unique String) instead of the id property. Has anyone done this? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You have two choices: 1. You create your custom `linkTo` handlebars helper, or 2. Or your hook into the `model` hook of your route to alter the deserialization, and the `serialize` hook also in the route for serialization. In this hooks you are able to alter the default behavior from the `linkTo` helper...

Comment: Thanks @intuitivepixel, I'll try both options.

Answer (score 0):

> You have two choices:
>
> > 1. You create your custom linkTo handlebars helper, or
> > 2. Or your hook into the model hook of your route to alter the deserialization, and the serialize hook also in the route for serialization. In this hooks you are able to alter the default behavior from the linkTo helper